# Hydrating an object generated with a doctrine native query, without it's ID Field

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine's native query feature according to [Doctrine Native Queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).I'm using a stored procedure to retrieve the data I want, and have created an entity for it that acts like a wrapper, let's call this Entity `Foo`.this Entity has a single one-to-one association field as it's primary key to Entity `Bar`.
However in the stored procedure I do not retrieve `Bar`'s Id field, and that in turn causes not to retrieve the primary key for `Foo` this will cause Doctrine's Hydrator (`Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator`) to return a `null` result instead of the real one, because of line `473` of the `ObjectHydrator`. is there a way around this except for adding the primary key of `Bar` to the result of the stored Procedure? (I will test this out and report back)

---

#### The Results from trying to add the primary key of Bar Entity:

the mapping metadata for `Foo`:

```
#Foo.orm.yml
Symf\TestBundle\Entity\Foo:
    type: entity
    id: 
        bar:
            associationKey: true
    oneToOne:
        bar:
            targetEntity: Symf\TestBundle\Entity\Bar
            joinColumn:
                name: bar_ID
                referencedColumnName: id
```

---

```
#Bar.orm.yml
Symf\TestBundle\Entity\Bar:
    type: Entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: 
                strategy: IDENTITY
```

---

So in my `ResultSetMapping` instance for mapping the data of the StoredProcedure to Foo Entity I used the following code:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult("Symf\\TestBundle\\Entity\\Foo", 'f')
        ->addMetaResult('f', 'Bar_SQL_column_name_in_stored_procedure', 'bar', true);
```

the last parameter signifies that this is a primary key of the Foo Entity.
But Now I get the following Error:

> Undefined index: bar_ID in /path/to/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2532

"bar_ID" is the name of the `joinColumn` specified in Foo's mapping.
This seems like a bug to me, because doctrine should ignore columnNames when using custom `ResultSetMappings`. is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: It didn't work, even with the primary key of `Bar` included

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Doctrine docs state that the third argument to `addMetaResult` should be the column name mentioned in the mapping and not the field name